# Mandatory fields and selecting drop down list values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, I have two fields, one a selection (drop down) list and the other an input textbox, both different question's.

My question is, if I choose *only one* value in the **selection list** (first question), the **textbox** (second question) must be 6 characters or numbers in length. Otherwise, the other values chosen in the selection list can be 10 characters long in the textbox.

How can I write this in Javascript form without the use of regex and within ?

I have written parts of this script but I would like to see how others can write it. My sole problem is to get the rest of the **other** values to be 10 characters long.

I'd also like to add that the first question does not need to be a selection list. I made it this way for the html to be more presentable and organised.

This is my script (so far):

```
function imposeMaxLength(object, limit) { 
   var num = document.getElementById("Number").value;
    if (num == "3") {
    document.getElementById("Type").value  {
    return (object.value.length <= limit);
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="number">Number:</label>
   <select size="1" id="Number">
   <option disabled>...</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
 </select>

<br>Type:<input type="text" id="Type" onkeypress="return imposeMaxLength(this,6);"><br>

<input type="button" value="submit"/>
```

Please help.

Comment: I would love to help but don't understand your question, are you trying to set the max length of characters on the text input based on the number from the select input?

Comment: @faithfulprogrammer yes, exactly. When you select the number 3, the text input should be 6 characters and the other containing letters should be 10 characters.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need this

```
<script>
   $('#Number').on('change', function () {
      var value=this.value;
      if(value==1)
        {
            $("#Type").attr('maxlength','6');
        }
      else
        {
            $("#Type").attr('maxlength','10');
        }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Based on @user3463017 comment above, this is how I would answer it as well, except for changing the 1 to a 3.

Answer (score 0):

This sets the maxlength to the required value whenever the Select element changes. So if you do select multiple values, then the maxlength will change to 10, otherwise, if only 1 item is selected it will have a maxlength of 6.

```
<div>
   <select size="1" id="Number" multiple>
   <option disabled>...</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="Type" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" value="submit"/>
```

```
$("#Number").on('change', function() {
  var selects = $(this).find('option:selected');
  if(selects.length > 1) {
    $("#Type").attr('maxlength', 10);
  } else {
    $("#Type").attr('maxlength', 6);
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SetEy/5/)

Answer (score 0):

u may simply use the property maxlength:

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="Type" maxlength="1"/><!-- default value in select -->

<select onchange="imposeMaxLength(this.value);">
```

**js**

```
<script>
    function imposeMaxLength(max) {
      document.getElementById("Type").maxlength = max;
    }
</script>
```